# pop up to open pdf does not work on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i use a little java script to open pdf documents in a smaller tab:

```js
// JavaScript Document
function openHeyPopup(objectLink) {

 window.open(objectLink, "Externer Link",  "width=700,height=600,scrollbars=yes");

}

function initHeyPopup()
{
 
 if (!document.getElementsByTagName){ return; }
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

 // loop through all anchor tags
 for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
  var anchor = anchors[i];

  if (anchor.getAttribute("href") && (anchor.getAttribute("rel") == "heypopup")){
   anchor.onclick = function () {openHeyPopup(this); return false;}
  }
 }

}

function addLoadEvent(func)
{ 
 var oldonload = window.onload;
 if (typeof window.onload != 'function'){
     window.onload = func;
 } else {
  window.onload = function(){
  oldonload();
  func();
  }
 }

}

addLoadEvent(initHeyPopup); // run initLightbox onLoad
```

This works fine for chrome and firefox. But in Internet explorer i get a empty browser window.

http://www.interieursalon.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/web-interieursalon-portfolio.pdf

Anybody no how can i fix this for IE?

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Where does it fail? You're unlikely to get a helpful answer if you post a big block of code and ask "why doesn't it work?".

Comment: Also, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: If the popup opens, the posted code works, and this most likely has to do with the browser settings, the server settings on the server serving up the PDF's, or the adobe plugin used in the browser.

Comment: @nicolasMoise: thanks for your answer. the code works there is no error while debugging the script. i use IE 11.0.96

Comment: @adeno: thanks, browser settings i cant influence. but what you mean with server setting up to PDFs??

Comment: @tom84 by debugging I mean using `console.log` and/or breakpoints to understand why it would fail. Is the `onload` event firing or not? Is `initHeyPopup` being called, is the `for` inside loop being fired correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In IE due to security reasons, opening new tabs with insecure content is blocked. we can try out this below code which helps us in downloading the file.

```
//window.navigator checks for IE version if yes, it gets executed and in place of  data give your blob.

if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
            return window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(data, "data.pdf");
}
```